# How to get restricted properties from Web for whole collection in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to have few Web properties avalieble in my code which are not by default. For example, if I load Website with `clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Webs)`
I don't get the "HasUniqueRoleAssignments" property. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534974%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
I can easily get them with lambda expresion. It works fine for geting properties I want from a single website

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web,  website => website.Title,   website => website.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,  website => website.RoleAssignments);
```

but I want to get whole collection of websites at once. I was trying to do sth like this

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Webs,  website => website.Title,   website => website.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,  website => website.RoleAssignments);
```

but it didn't run.

Anyone knows how to solve this out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve [HasUniqueRoleAssignments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.securableobject.hasuniqueroleassignments.aspx) property for web site collection:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{            

    ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Webs, wcol => wcol.Include(w => w.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, w => w.Title, w => w.RoleAssignments));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var web in ctx.Web.Webs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
    }
}
```